# Creating a 32 bit wrapper for a 64 bit dll. Is this possible?

Tags: c#, c++, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I have a couple of dlls that are `x64`, with the `x86` versions not being released yet. I want to use these in a `x86` environment. There is no way to change any of the platforms of those factors.

I have tried searching the Internet, but to no avail. What I want to do is somehow create a `x86` library that can communicate with the `x64` ones. Is this possible at all? If so, how?

Preferably, the wrapper will be in `C#` code, though it has to be able to access `C++` dlls. (The `x64` libraries are written in `unmanaged C++`.)

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please do explain why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this within a single process. That's because a 32 bit process can only load 32 bit modules, and a 64 bit process can only load 64 bit modules.

The only way for your 64 bit code to call 32 bit code, and vice versa, is to use an out-of-proc solution. For example an out-of-proc COM server.

Comment: Thank you. Using a COM server and client seems to be a feasible solution for my problem.